# How to run a Python callback when Blender exits?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get a callback before Blender closes?

There are `bpy.app.handlers`. Unfortunately there is no handler for closing Blender.

So is there a way to to know in a script when blender is about to close?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While we could support this via [`bpy.app.handlers`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html), we decided not to add this since Python already supports exit callbacks, so you can use these (outside of Blender too - for any Python script).

See Python's [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module.

Simple example use:

```
def goodbye(name, adjective):
    print("Goodbye, %s, it was %s to meet you." % (name, adjective))

import atexit
atexit.register(goodbye, "Suzanne", "nice")
```

Note : To unregister the callback when disabling an add-on for instance, you can use :

```
atexit.unregister(callback)
```

Comment: ok. This works. But I have a problem with it. When running the script from blender this function gets registered. But when putting it into an addon I get this error:
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Comment: Try find which line causes the error, This will run when Blender is shutting down - so its possible you access data which is already freed.

Comment: I know this post is very old, but I wanted to add information in case anyone finds this post because of the same problem. If you try to access your add-on's preferences during this event, you will get an access violation error. I was able to access several things from Blender, but not my own addon's preferences. In my opinion, Blender should notify add-ons of a shutdown BEFORE any data is released.

Comment: where do you use atexit.register? i tried placing it in the add-on def register but it doesn't seem to work