# event "close program"

Tags: add-on

**Main question**:

in my addon, i create a python-thread, for do not blocking UI. (1) its wrong?)

thread created on checkbox-"on", and destroyed on "off".
problem when checkbox is "on". when i close blender, blender does not close :)

i find this [solutioin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48566/60187), but not work for me, callback not fired

i need thread for "filewatch", and do something on os "file-modified" event

how can I solve this problem?

**sub question**

i have a class extends from bpy.types.PropertyGroup and

```
checkbox-property = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name="Switch",
    description="",
    default=False,
    update=checkbox_update_handler
)
```

default=false not work in some cases.

how i can set always false, when blender\or new file startup

Thanks!

Comment: Properties of the window manager are not saved, and will have their default at start up.ii)  adding the following  `bl_options = {'SKIP_SAVE'}` on an operator property, makes it return to default after use. (not sure if / how it works for other props.  It's been my experience that threads and blender don't play well together if you are referencing blender data from the thread.  Might find [this recent post interesting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113912/is-automatic-reload-from-disk-confirmation-in-text-editor-possible/113937#113937) on auto-updating changed text files.

Comment: @batFINGER i no have a "operators" on checkbox i use "update-callback" function. but i moved propertyGroup to WindowManager and it helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution also based on atexit,
but thread need property daemon=True.
Then python interpreter do not wait he will complete the work and fires atexit-callback